# Apache - allow directory listing but downloading files require vaild-user

Tags: apache, file, directory, download, www-authenticate

I want to allow my friends to view all files in directory without logging .
But when they want to download file I want to authenticate them.
How to do this ?

Now I have something like this:

```
AuthUserFile /var/....../.htpasswd
AuthName "VIP"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `FilesMatch` rule.

Take a look at [The Ultimate .htaccess Guide](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html#Password_Protect_multiple_files) for more information.